# userID with google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am currently tracking video plays using the video id, like so:

```
onPlay: function(event) { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Features', 'Play', videoID]);
```

I thought I could just add another entry beneath the 1st, using the userID instead, so I could get a category for each user's id, but the javascript erred out.

```
onPlay: function(event) { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Features', 'Play', videoID]);    
onPlay: function(event) { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', store_user_id, 'Play', videoID]);
```

I understand that one can use userId, but I don't understand how to use in my context.
How can I add user tracking without ruining my current report scheme? I would like to have the user-specific tracking in a different category.

Comment: what is your error? Does it contain valuable info?

Comment: the javascript function is called getVideo(param1, etc...). The error is: 'function getVideo is not defined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no errors when I use this:

```
events: {
onPlay: function(event) { 
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', videoID]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', store_user_id, 'Play', videoID]);
}
```

so, instead of using function twice, I just use _gaq.push twice.

I guess we will wait to see what we get. If this works, I will come back and flag a final answer.

Comment: could even do `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', videoID], ['_trackEvent', store_user_id, 'Play', videoID]);` - [one push, multiple commands](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#MultipleCommands)

Comment: I am using this:
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', videoID], ['_trackEvent', store_user_id, 'Play', videoID]);

Not sure if the GA request is working. When the GA request goes out, I see response information for:<br/>
    ['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', videoID].

I don't see any response info from the second _trackEvent: 
    ['_trackEvent', store_user_id, 'Play', videoID]

Comment: trying doing a `console.log(store_user_id);` and see what it's returning. I'm guessing nothing...

Comment: It's definitely going out. Here is my console: _gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[51,Play,49071]":  ga_debug.js:24
Track Event

Comment: Are you passing 51 as a number or a string? `console.log(typeof store_user_id);` Google Analytics event category expects a [string](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview).

Comment: I tried both a string and a number. Neither works. The store_user_id shows in the console as well.

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: @Blexy I used your combined approach as well. this is working!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the userId in a hit-level custom dimension and have it fire on each hit to GA. Then use a custom segment e.g. userId equals 123, and look at all actions, events, pageviews for that specific user.

**EDIT:**

I mistook your code for Universal Analytics, which if you're doing any new implementations, I would highly suggest migrating as you'll get all the new bells and whistles that GA has to offer.

But to illustrate how you would track userId at the hit-level, you'll first need to [get the clientId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId):

```
var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
```

*Note: if you have multiple trackers, this will only retrieve the first one, and you'll have to wait until ga loads completely in order to get access to the ga object.

Next, you would set the `clientId` in the custom dimension. Set it prior to the pageview, so that every hit on the page gets tagged with the clientId.

You *should* be able to set it prior to the `ga('send', 'pageview');` command; however, the ga object might not be available, and then you won't have a value for the customDimension.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');

  var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', clientId);

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Could I see a sample? is your idea similar to the code I already have running?

Comment: I am supplying a user Id, not interested in the client id.These are custom user Ids.

Comment: Would work the same way. Just replace clientId with userId in the custom dimension.